# How to create function prototype that recognizes arguments passed by reference in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, x86, calling-conventions

I have a function prototype generated by IDA that looks like this:

[image]

However, it looks like there is a struct being referenced at the instruction **lea edi, [esp+290h+var_240]**. I would like IDA to reference this passed address as an argument in its function prototype.

I have tried the approach below, but it is clear that it does not work.

[image]

What I would like to see is something like this

[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the function signature should be something like:

```
int __usercall Call_HTTP@<eax>(int x, int y, void* http_object@<edi>);
```

- `__usercall` means the calling convention for the function is not a standard one (like stdcall, cdecl, etc.) as the function passes two arguments on stack and one in edi.
- `@<eax>` : function returns a value in eax register.
- `int x` and `int y` are passed on the stack.
- `void* http_object@<edi>` : http_object is a void* passed through the edi register.

You can change the type of the `http_object` by adding a proper structure for this object to the known IDA structures and pass the real type instead of `void*`.

For more information on function signature, see the IDA help on [Set function/item type](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1361.shtml).

**Edit**

The right signature should be:

```
int __userpurge Call_HTTP@<eax>(int x, int y, void* http_object@<edi>);
```

As stated by @itsbriany:

- for `__stdcall` and `__userpurge` calling conventions, the callee cleans up the stack.
- in `__cdecl` and `__usercall` conventions, the caller cleans up the stack.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I would also like to add that the calling convention would be **__userpurge** because the calling convention was originally **__stdcall**. This is because in **__stdcall** and **__userpurge**, the callee cleans up the stack. In **__cdecl** and **__usercall**, the caller cleans up the stack :)

Comment: @itsbriany Oops, sorry for the error... Nice catch! I'll edit my post.